# Writing data into a CSV file by two different CSV files

Tags: ruby, csv, writefile

So, i'm learning ruby and i've been stuck with this for a long time and i need some help.

I need to write to a CSV file from two different CSV files and i have the code to do it but in 2 different functions and i need the two files together in one.

So thats the code:

```
require 'CSV'

class Plantas <
   Struct.new( :code)
end

class Especies <
   Struct.new(:id, :type, :code, :name_es, :name_ca, :name_en, :latin_name, :customer_id )
end

def ecode

   f_inECODE = File.open("pflname.csv", "r")                  #get EPPOCODE
   f_out=CSV.open("plantas.csv", "w+", :headers => true) #outputfile

   f_inECODE.each_line do |line|

   fields = line.split(',')

   newPlant = Plantas.new

   newPlant.code = fields[2].tr_s('"', '').strip #eppocode

       plant = [newPlant.code] #linies a imprimir
       f_out <<  plant

   end
end

def data

   f_dataspices=File.open("spices.csv", "r")
   f_out=CSV.open("plantas.csv", "w+", :headers => true) #outputfile

   f_dataspices.each_line do |line|

       fields = line.split(',')
       newEspecies = Especies.new
       
       newEspecies.id = fields[0].tr_s('"', '').strip 
       newEspecies.type = fields[1].tr_s('"', '').strip 
       newEspecies.code = fields[2].tr_s('"', '').strip 
       newEspecies.name_es = fields[3].tr_s('"', '').strip 
       newEspecies.name_ca = fields[4].tr_s('"', '').strip 
       newEspecies.name_en = fields[5].tr_s('"', '').strip 
       newEspecies.latin_name = fields[6].tr_s('"', '').strip
       newEspecies.customer_id = fields[7].tr_s('"', '').strip 
       
           especia = [newEspecies.id,newEspecies.type,newEspecies.code,newEspecies.name_es,newEspecies.name_ca,newEspecies.name_en,newEspecies.latin_name,newEspecies.customer_id] 
           f_out <<  especia
   end
end

data 
ecode
```

And the wished output would be like this: species.csv + ecode.csv

```
"id","type","code","name_es","name_ca","name_en","latin_name","customer_id","ecode"
7205,"DunSpecies",NULL,"0","0","0","",11630,LEECO
7437,"DunSpecies",NULL,"0","Xicoira","0","",5273,LEE3O
7204,"DunSpecies",NULL,"0","0","0","",11630,L4ECO
```

And the actual is this:

```
"id","type","code","name_es","name_ca","name_en","latin_name","customer_id"
7205,"DunSpecies",NULL,"0","0","0","",11630
7437,"DunSpecies",NULL,"0","Xicoira","0","",5273
7204,"DunSpecies",NULL,"0","0","0","",11630
```

(without ecode)

From one side i have the ecode and from the other the whole data i just need to put it together.

I'd like to put all together in the same file (plantas.csv)
I did in two different functions because I don't know how to put all together with one foreach I would like to put all in the same function but I don't how doing it.
If someone could help me to get this code all in one function and writing the results in the same file I would be so grateful.

An example of the input of the file ecode.csv (in which I just want the ecode field) is this:

```
"""identifier"",""datatype"",""code"",""lang"",""langno"",""preferred"",""status"",""creation"",""modification"",""country"",""fullname"",""authority"",""shortname"""
"""N1952"",""PFL"",""LEECO"",""la"",""1"",""0"",""N"",""06/06/2000"",""09/03/2010"","""",""Leea coccinea non"",""Planchon"",""Leea coccinea non"""
"""N2974"",""PFL"",""LEECO"",""en"",""1"",""0"",""N"",""06/06/2000"",""21/02/2011"","""",""west Indian holly"","""",""West Indian holly"""
```

An example of the input of the file data.csv (in which I want all the fields) is this:

```
"id","type","code","name_es","name_ca","name_en","latin_name","customer_id"
7205,"DunSpecies",NULL,"0","0","0","",11630
7437,"DunSpecies",NULL,"0","Xicoira","0","",5273
```

And the way to link both files is by creating a third file in which i write everything in it!
At least this is my idea, i dont know if there is a simpler way to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: can you give us an example of the input CSVs, and the way in which the 2 files are linked?

Comment: I just updated the post! is that all need to know? 
Thanks!

Comment: Where is "LEE3O" and "L4ECO" supposed to come from? I don't see it anywhere in the example CSV files. I assume it's "the ecode field" you wanted. How are the data sets matched? Line by line or by some identifier?

Comment: LEE3O, L4ECO and LECCO are some examples  of the ecode and thats the third field in the ecode.csv.
Every single field of both fiels have an identifier and all are separateds by a line.
Hope that answer yours questions!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaning up `ecode.csv` made it more challenging, but here is what I came up with:

In case, `data.csv` and `ecode.csv` are matched by row numbers:

```rb
require 'csv'

data = CSV.read('data.csv', headers: true).to_a
headers = data.shift << 'eppocode'

double_quoted_ecode = CSV.read('ecode.csv')
ecodeIO = StringIO.new
ecodeIO.puts double_quoted_ecode.to_a
ecodeIO.rewind
ecode = CSV.parse(ecodeIO, headers: true)

CSV.open('plantas.csv', 'w+') do |plantas|
  plantas << headers
  data.each.with_index do |row, idx|
    planta = row + [ecode['code'][idx]]
    plantas << planta
  end
end
```

Using your example files, this gives you the following `plantas.csv`:

```
id,type,code,name_es,name_ca,name_en,latin_name,customer_id,eppocode
7205,DunSpecies,NULL,0,0,0,"",11630,LEECO
7437,DunSpecies,NULL,0,Xicoira,0,"",5273,LEECO
```

In case, entries are matched by `data.csv`'s `id` and `ecode.csv`'s `identifier`:

```rb
require 'csv'

data = CSV.read('data.csv', headers: true)
headers = data.headers << 'eppocode'

double_quoted_ecode = CSV.read('ecode.csv')
ecodeIO = StringIO.new
ecodeIO.puts double_quoted_ecode.to_a
ecodeIO.rewind
ecode = CSV.parse(ecodeIO, headers: true)

CSV.open('plantas.csv', 'w+') do |plantas|
  plantas << headers
  data.each do |row|
    id = row['id']
    ecode_row = ecode.find { |entry| entry['identifier'] == id } || {}
    planta = row << ecode_row['code']
    plantas << planta
  end
end
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**Data**

Let's begin by creating the two CSV files. To make the results easier to follow I have arbitrarily removed some of the fields in each file, and changed one field value.

*ecode.csv*

```
ecode = '"""identifier"",""datatype"",""code"",""lang"",""langno"",""preferred"",""status"",""creation"",""modification"",""country"",""fullname"",""authority"",""shortname"""    """N1952"",""PFL"",""LEECO"",""la"",""1"",""0"",""N"",""06/06/2000"",""09/03/2010"","""",""Leea coccinea non"",""Planchon"",""Leea coccinea non"""    """N2974"",""PFL"",""LEEC1"",""en"",""1"",""0"",""N"",""06/06/2000"",""21/02/2011"","""",""west Indian holly"","""",""West Indian holly"""'

File.write('ecode.csv', ecode)
  #=> 452
```

*data.csv*

```
data = '"id","type","code","customer_id"\n7205,"DunSpecies",NULL,11630\n7437,"DunSpecies",NULL,,5273'

File.write('data.csv', data)
  #=> 90
```

**Code**

```
CSV.open('plantas.csv', 'w') do |csv_out|
  converter = ->(s) { s.delete('"') }

  epposcode = CSV.foreach('ecode.csv',
    headers:true,
    header_converters: [converter],
    converters: [converter]
  ).map { |csv| csv["code"] }

  headers = CSV.open('data.csv', &:readline) << 'epposcode'
  csv_out << headers

  CSV.foreach('data.csv', headers:true) do |row|
    csv_out << (row << epposcode.shift)
  end
end
  #=> 90
```

**Result**

Let's see what was written.

```
puts File.read('plantas.csv')

id,type,code,customer_id,epposcode
7205,DunSpecies,NULL,11630,LEECO
7437,DunSpecies,NULL,,5273,LEEC1
```

**Explanation**

The structure we want is the following.

```
CSV.open('plantas.csv', 'w') do |csv_out|
  epposcode = <array of 'code' field values from 'ecode.csv'>
  headers = <headers from 'data.csv' to which 'epposcode' is appended>
  csv_out << headers
  CSV.foreach('data.csv', headers:true) do |row|
    csv_out << <row of 'data.csv' to which an element of epposcode is appended>>
  end
end
```

[CSV::open](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-open) is the main CSV method for writing files and [CSV::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach) is generally my method-of-choice for reading CSV files. I could have instead written the following.

```
csv_out = CSV.open('plantas.csv', 'w')

epposcode = <array of 'code' field values from 'ecode.csv'>
headers = <headers from 'data.csv' to which 'epposcode' is appended>
csv_out << headers
CSV.foreach('data.csv', headers:true) do |row|
  csv_out << <row of 'data.csv' to which an element of epposcode is appended>>
end

csv_out.close
```

but using a block is convenient because the file is closed before returning from the block.

---

It is convenient to use a converter for both the header fields and the row fields:

```
converter = ->(s) { s.delete('"') }
```

This is a proc (I've defined a lambda) that removes double quotes from strings. They are specified as two of `foreach`'s optional arguments:

```
  epposcode = CSV.foreach('ecode.csv',
    headers:true,
    header_converters: [converter],
    converters: [converter]
  )
```

Search for "Data Converters" in the [CSV](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) doc.

---

We invoke `foreach` without a block to return an enumerator, so it can be chained to `map`:

```
epposcode = CSV.foreach('ecode.csv',
  headers:true,
  header_converters: [converter],
  converters: [converter]
).map { |csv| csv["code"] }
```

For the example,

```
epposcode
  #=> ["LEECO", "LEEC1"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer anyways! Helped a lot understanding how ruby works with CSV